# ¿Por qué el value no detecta el id de mi option? me dice undifined variable id_conductor

Tags: php, postgresql

el valor de mi opción no es tomado, dice que no defino la variable, si alguien pudiera notar algo o tener una mejor forma de hacerlo

la consulta la tengo separada.

```
<select name="conductor_bus">

                <?php
                while($obj=pg_fetch_object($consulta)){ ?>

                    <option value=<?php echo $obj->$id_conductor ?>><?php echo $obj->nombre_conductor;?></option>

                    <?php
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Tienes que hacerle `var_dump` a `$obj` para saber qué estás recibiendo de la consulta. SI tú no lo sabes, imagínate nosotros. Si PHP dice que esa variable no existe, posiblemente tenga razón.

Comment: por intuicion puedo notar que en el value pusiste: 
<?php echo $obj->$id_conductor ?>
y en realidad deberia ser:
<?php echo $obj->id_conductor ?>

es decir el id_conductor sin el simbolo de dolar  $

Comment: muchas gracias a ambos, estuve en eso casi todo el día, logre corregir el error-